# No modificar cadena original en una función

Tags: c, string

Hice una función para saber si dos palabras son anagramas...Pero no quería modificar las dos cadenas originales. Y mi función, modifica una de las cadenas, la cadena que bajo en un `char`* auxiliar (`sAux`) (justamente lo hice para no modificar la cadena original). A mi entender, el puntero auxiliar esta apuntando al mismo lugar que el puntero que llega como parámetro a la función (el de la cadena que no quiero modificar). Pero no se me ocurre como solucionarlo.

Les muestro la función. La cadena que se me modifica es la llamada `s1` (`const char*s1` -parámetro que recibe la función). 
 Cabe destacar que no debo modificar las cadenas originales y debo usar aritmetica de punteros.

```
int esAnagrama(const char *s1, const char *s2)//s1 se modifica
{
char*sAux=(char*)s1,*s2Aux=sAux;//puedo observar que apuntan a lo mismo- a la misma direccion de memoria.
int i=0,j=0,k=0;
while(*(sAux+i)&&*(s2+k))
{
    if((*(sAux+i)!=*(s2+k))&&*(s2+k)!=' '&&*(sAux+i)!=*(s2+k)+32&&*(sAux+i)!=*(s2+k)-32)
       {
        if(*(sAux+i)!=' ')
        {
            *(s2Aux+j)=*(sAux+i);///si no encontro la letra la dejo en s2aux
            j++;
        }
       }
        else k++;//si encontro la letra sigo recorriendo la cadena
    i++;
    if(*(sAux+i)=='\0'&&i!=j)
    {
        *(s2Aux+j)='\0';
        sAux=s2Aux;
        i=j=0;
    }
}
return(!*(s2+k)&&!*(sAux+i));
}
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de como solucionarlo para que `s1`, cadena original, no se modifique? Intente reservar memoria para el `char*` en el que bajo la cadena original pero dio el resultado que esperaba.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facil, crea una cadena temporal dentro de la función:

```
int esAnagrama(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
  char* temporal = (char*)malloc(strlen(s1)+1 * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(temporal,s1);

  // trabajas con temporal en vez de con s1
  char*sAux=temporal,*s2Aux=sAux;

  // ...

  int to_return = !*(s2+k)&&!*(sAux+i);
  free(temporal);

  return to_return;
}
```

Comment: Gracias eferion! Asi funciona, si. Voy a ver como reemplazo el strcpy de una manera óptima, se me ocurre solo caracter por caracter con un while, debido a que no deberia usar funciones de otra libreria. Si tenes algun comentario al  respecto con gusto recibo alguna sugerencia!

Comment: @micaela si no puedes usar funciones de otra librería sí, puede ser una solución... mejor si puedes ponerlo como función independiente... así no te llena el algoritmo de código supérfluo

Comment: Si! Seria mucho mejor, de igual manera tu respuesta soluciona mi problema. Muchas gracias @eferion!

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Alguna sugerencia de como solucionarlo para que `s1`, cadena original, no se modifique?

Claro. Lo sorprendente es que para comprobar si has dado con un anagrama modifiques los datos de entrada, ¡no es necesario! Veamos lo que es un [anagrama](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagrama):

> Un anagrama (del griego ἀνά -ana-, prefijo que significa "de vuelta", y γράμμα -gramma-, "letra") es una palabra o frase que resulta de la transposición de letras de otra palabra o frase. Dicho de otra forma, una palabra es anagrama de otra si las dos **tienen las mismas letras, con el mismo número de apariciones, pero en un orden diferente**.

Dado que necesitas contar las letras en ambas cadenas, vamos a crear dos búferes de recuento:

```
char recuento1[1 << (8 * sizeof(char))] = {0},
     recuento2[1 << (8 * sizeof(char))] = {0};
```

Estos dos búferes tienen una posición por cada letra posible. Lo siguiente que debemos saber es que si las cadenas entrantes no tienen la misma longitud no es posible que sean anagramas, así que contamos su longitud:

```
int longitud1 = strlen(s1),
    longitud2 = strlen(s2);
```

Sabiendo esto, recorremos ambas cadenas a la vez contando las letras de cada una:

```
for (int i = 0; i < longitud1; ++i)
{
    ++recuento1[tolower(s1[i])];
    ++recuento2[tolower(s2[i])];
}
```

Paso la letra a minúscula para que (por ejemplo) "*Mary*" y "*Army*" cuenten como anagrama. Una vez hecho esto, si ambas palabras son anagramas los búferes serán iguales:

```
return memcmp(recuento1, recuento2, sizeof(recuento1)) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

Como puedes ver, no ha sido necesario modificar ninguna de las cadenas de entrada, este sería el código completo:

```
int esAnagrama(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int resultado = 0;

    char recuento1[1 << (8 * sizeof(char))] = {0},
         recuento2[1 << (8 * sizeof(char))] = {0};

    int longitud1 = strlen(s1),
        longitud2 = strlen(s2);

    if (longitud1 == longitud2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < longitud1; ++i)
        {
            ++recuento1[tolower(s1[i])];
            ++recuento2[tolower(s2[i])];
        }

        resultado = memcmp(recuento1, recuento2, sizeof(recuento1)) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DwzN1BSVdYRluHd6)</kbd>.

Ten en cuenta que el código que he compartido no considerará como anagrama frases con igual cantidad de letras pero diferente espaciado como "*Tom Marvolo Riddle*" con "*I am Lord Voldemort*". Podría quedarte como ejercicio adicional resolver este problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Paula_plus_plus!!Voy a probarlo también!

Comment: Que gustazo cuando una pregunta de C / C++ tiene más de una respuesta  y no son calcos entre sí XD